# Trouble Converting gdal_calc.py output to Floating Point

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, gdal-calc, floating-point

I am new to coding.

I'm looking to create an NDVI on S2 data using gdal_calc.py in a Jupyter Notebook. I've downloaded imagery from [GEE using code provided by the JRC, European Commission.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e33154ce635c8e7e240742d5d8a7850f) I selected Bands 4, 8, 11 for download so I could perform NDVI and NDWI. I'm able to get the gdal_calc.py command to run but the output data is in Byte form even after passing 'Float32' as the 'type'. The odd thing is that when I use !glad_info -mm result.tif the results say the Type=Byte, but the computed Min/Max is 0.000,253.000. I feel like there are numerous problems with my script as my result.tif should have pixel values between -1 and 1, and this is obviously well outside the range.

```
!gdal_calc.py -A '...Nigeria_Test.tif' --A_band=1 -B '...Nigeria_Test.tif' --outfile=result.tif --calc="(B-A)/(B+A)" --B_band=2 --type Float32
```

What am I doing wrong?

My goal is to test this on this much smaller AOI so I can apply this over all tiles in the country.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script you shared gives options for different output data scales. I am assuming you used the "Optimized 0-255". If so, then the input data are byte dtypes with a range of 0-255 and the results will have the same range because there is no rescaling occurring when calculating the data.

I would suggest to export your data using the "Raw 0-10000" option so that the data is scaled reflectance and you are sure how to rescale the data. Then in your `gdal_calc` command add the scaling factors `--calc="(B*0.0001-A*0.0001)/(B*0.0001+A*0.0001)"`